# Update ElasticSearch document using Python requests

Tags: elasticsearch, python-requests, python-3.7

I am implementing ElasticSearch 7.1.1 in my application using Python requests library. I have successfully created a document in the elastic index using

`r = requests.put(url, auth=awsauth, json=document, headers=headers)`

However, while updating an existing document, the JSON body(containing to be updated values) that I pass to the method, replaces the original document. How do I overcome this? Thank you.

Comment: You need to write python equivalent for [update api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#docs-update).

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
document = {
    "doc": {
        "field_1": "value_1",
        "field_2": "value_2"
    },
    "doc_as_upsert": True
}

...
r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=document, headers=headers)
```

1. It should be `POST` instead of `PUT`
2. You can update existing fields and also add new fields.

Refer the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/docs-update.html#doc_as_upsert) in the comment posted by Nishant Saini.